# issues with load order of functions and variables (Scope issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling with getting this firing in the right order.

I'm defining the functions prior to `$(document).ready`, however, I'm using jQuery in the variables, so they need to be loaded after jquery.js is, so they're inside the `$(document).ready` as well.

My Problem is, the way I have it setup, `radioGroupStyle()` is being called inside the `windowSize()` function so classes change base on window size (it's also being called on form submit), but `radioGroupStyle()` is using the `radio` variable, which is returned undefined because it's defined in the `$(document).ready`.

Should I just write the variables in javascript (not jQuery) and put them at the top of the script? Is there a better way to write this or order this so it alleviates this issue?

[Original Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/darcher/Lje2g0wp/)

[Pointy's Suggestion Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/darcher/Lje2g0wp/1/)

[Possibly working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/darcher/Lje2g0wp/2/)

```
function supportsHtml5Validation() {
    return typeof document.createElement('input').checkValidity === 'function';
}

function windowSize() {
    windowHeight = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $(window).height();
    windowWidth = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : $(window).width();
    radioGroupStyle();
}
windowSize();
$(window).resize(function () {
    windowSize();
});

function isValid(input) {
    $(input).addClass('valid').removeClass('invalid').attr('data-validity', 'valid');
}

function inValid(input) {
    $(input).addClass('invalid').removeClass('valid').attr('data-validity', 'invalid');
}

function isEmpty(input) {
    if (!$.trim($(input).val())) {
        $(input).removeClass('invalid').removeClass('valid').removeClass('invalid-radio').attr('data-validity', 'null');
    }
}

function radioGroupStyle() {
    $('.group').each(function () {
        if (windowWidth >= 800 && radio.not(':checked')) {
            $(this).addClass('invalid-radio');
            radio.on('change', function () {
                $(this).closest('.group').removeClass('invalid-radio');
            });
        } else if (windowWidth < 800 && radio.not(':checked')) {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('invalid-radio');
            $(this).closest('.field').addClass('invalid-radio');
            radio.on('change', function () {
                $(this).closest('.field').removeClass('invalid-radio');
            });
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    if (!supportsHtml5Validation()) {
        return;
    }
    var timer = 0,
        input = $('input').not('[type=radio]'),
        radio = $('input[type=radio]'),
        select = $('select'),
        notRequired = input.not('[required]'),
        form = $('form');

    input.on('keyup', function () {

        clearTimeout(timer);
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) === '') {
            isEmpty(this);
            return false;
        } else if (!this.checkValidity()) {
            timer = setTimeout(inValid(this), 300);
        } else if (this.checkValidity()) {
            isValid(this);
        }
    });

    select.on('change', function () {
        if (!this.checkValidity()) {
            inValid(this);
        } else {
            isValid(this);
        }
    });

    form.on('submit', function (e) {

        input.add(select).each(function () {
            if (!this.checkValidity()) {
                e.preventDefault();
                inValid(this);
            } else {
                isValid(this);
            }
        });

        radioGroupValidation();

    });

    $('button[type=reset]').on('click', function () {
        console.log('reset clicked');
        $('.group, .field, input, select').each(function () {
            isEmpty(this);
        });
    });

    if (notRequired) {
        notRequired.on('keyup', function () {
            if ($.trim($(this).val()) === '') {
                isEmpty(this);
                return false;
            } else if (!$(this).val().match($(this).attr('pattern'))) {
                notRequired.each(function () {
                    inValid(this);
                });
            } else if ($(this).val().match($(this).attr('pattern'))) {
                notRequired.each(function () {
                    isValid(this);
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe just move the `windowSize` stuff into the "ready" handler.

Comment: You are facing a scope issue, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bzt2dkta%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Comment: @Pointy Moving the `windowSize` still leaves `radio` as undefined, and moving the `radioGroupStyle` inside the 'ready' handler makes it work, but it then fires the `radioGroupStyle` function on document ready, not just on submit. I'll add a fiddle.

Comment: Can you move the first call of windowSize() into ready()?
Can you ad a guard inside radioGroupStyle() so if !radio then it exits?